# determine basis for given vector space

Tags: vector-spaces

let us consider following problem

> 1. A subsepace $S$ of a vector space $V$ is given.
>
>    Determine a basis for $S$ and extend your basis for $S$ to obtain a basis for $V$.
>
>    $V=P_2$, $S$ is the subspace consisting of all polynomials of the form
>      $$(2a_1+a_2)x^2+(a_1+a_2)x+3(a_1-a_2).$$

we know that for  polynomials of order  $2$ basis can be represented by following set of vectors

$(1,x,x^2)$
 now we want to extend this basis for  vector space $V$,does it means that  for  vector space $V$  linear combination of basis of $S$  will be another basis or?clearly if $V$ is  vector space of order more then $2$,we can add more  element like $x^3$,but in this case what we should do?thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you rewrite the defining equation for $S$ as all polynomials of the form $a_1(2x^2+x+3)+a_2(x^2+x-1)$, then it becomes clear that $S$ is defined as the span of $2x^2+x+3$ and $x^2+x-1$, which you can verify are linearly independent, hence form a basis for $S$. All that remains to do, then, is to find a third linearly independent vector to extend this to a basis for $V$.

Comment: should i  search it using brute force  method or  just by guessing or is there any other method?thanks for reply

Comment: There are many methods; it shouldn't be difficult to guess and verify (in which case it will be easier to verify spanning rather than linear independence).

Comment: does there exist any matrix form?because mostly my friend was interested in this problem for his exam

Comment: Well, this is of limited use because it only works in three dimensions, but in the circumstance of a three dimensional vector space and two vectors written in terms of an obvious basis (here $1$, $x$, and $x^2$), you can use a method you might remember from calculus of finding a third perpendicular vector.

Comment: but how to apply  cross product there?by the way thanks very much

Comment: Identify polynomials with elements of $\mathbb R^3$, as in $(2, 1, 3)$ and $(1, 1, -1)$.

Comment: aaaaa,thanks very much,ok  so my friend i dont know if he is aware of this,but  thanks for help